# Custom icon font shows up in my localhost environment but not on my external server

Tags: css, fonts, font-awesome, glyphicons

Summary: I have a problem where a custom font (generated at Glypther) and included in my website will render/show on my localhost. But when the site is moved to my hosting provider, it does not render/show at all.

Here is the generated iconfont.css file (it is the .icon-logo, that is used). There are other files generated that I have not included.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'IconFont';
    src: url('../fonts/IconFont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/IconFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/IconFont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/IconFont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/IconFont.svg#IconFont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
[class*='icon-']:before{
    display: inline-block;
   font-family: 'IconFont';
   font-style: normal;
   font-weight: normal;
   line-height: 2;
   font-size: 2.3em;
   -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
   -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
}
.icon-Block:before{content:'\0041';}
.icon-Chat:before{content:'\0042';}
.icon-Favorite:before{content:'\0043';}
.icon-Interested:before{content:'\0044';}
.icon-Unlock:before{content:'\0045';}
.icon-Wink:before{content:'\0046';}
.icon-Logo:before{content:'\0047';}
```

There are a few styles in the css (style.css) and uses bootstrap:

```
.navbar-inverse .icon-Logo {
    float: left;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default.lo-nav .icon-Logo {
    color: #525252;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

And here is the code that uses the logo:

```
<i class="icon icon-Logo"></i>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Website name</a>
```

When I inspect the code (using Chrome) where the logo properly shows up on the localhost, I see the following:

```
<i class="icon icon-Logo>
  ::before
</i> == $0
```

However, when inspecting the code on the external hosting (where the logo is not being displayed), I see the following:

```
<i class="icon icon-Logo></i>
```

The only other thing to mention and I am not sure if it is relevant is that my external host (HG) URL is an add-on domain (where the DNS has not yet been update i.e. I access the site with http:/(accountname)/website/ and I use Chrome vHost extension. The reason why I don't think this is relevant is because there are other icon fonts css included (added by others) that render under both local and external hosting conditions.

I would appreciate any insights. Thanks!

Comment: I should mention that I checked the permissions for all the files on the hosting provider and they are all 0644 (meaning) owner can read/write but all others can read. This was the same as for the set of icons fonts that are working also.

Comment: Have you updated your font files?

Comment: No. None of the files were updated. I simply ftp-ed all the files from my local environment to the hosting provider.

Comment: I ended up re-generating the font icons again at Glyphter and re-incorporating them into the site (using different filename). This time around it worked on both local and hosted environments. I could not tell you what was different .. Strange.

Comment: if that was the solution, please post it as an answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting my own answer here ... I ended up re-generating the font icons again at Glyphter and re-incorporating them into the site (using different filename). This time around it worked on both local and hosted environments. I could not tell you what was different. Sorry.